# GetFiles not getting the correct files

Tags: c#

I need to get all `.txt` files in all subfolders of a specified folder so I do:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(reportsFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

However, in some folders I also have files with extensions like `.txt_TODO`, and these are also being retrieved by `GetFiles`.

How can I skip these files?

Comment: You can get all files and then filter them by regualr expression ".+\.txt$"

Comment: I just tried it. And I got only .txt files.

Comment: Or add .`Where(file => Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140313-00/?p=1513

Comment: Use this pattern `"?*.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter the result by comparing the extension to ".txt", e.g. using LINQ:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(reportsFolder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).Equals(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: `.EnumerateFiles` instead of `.GetFiles` will be better choice (no premature materialization) in the context

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Sure; but then also the ToArray() has to be removed... What's better depends on what he is doing with the returned collection.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Even with final `.ToArray()` switching to `EnumerateFiles` seems to be a better option: the materialized result of `Directory.GetFiles` is immediately lazily enumerated by `Where`, so replacing it with `EnumerateFiles` doesn't change the behaviour if the final `.ToArray()` is left intact.